# Integration of exponential functions: $\int_0^\infty e^{-({x^2}/{y^2})-y^2}\; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How I am to solve this integral? I am not able to use any of the methods.
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-({x^2}/{y^2})-y^2}\; dx$$

Comment: Hint: `y` is just a constant because of `dx`.

Comment: ooo yeah really... thanks.,

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word.  "Evaluate" could serve.  One solves problems, one solves equations.  One evaluates expressions.  One could solve the problem of evaluating this integral, or one could evaluate the integral, but one does not "solve" integrals.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{\Large-\frac{x^2}{y^2}-y^2}\ dx=e^{\Large-y^2}\int_0^\infty e^{\Large-\frac{x^2}{y^2}}\ dx,
$$
where the last form integral is [Gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html):
$$
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}}.
$$
Letting $a=\dfrac1{y^2}$, then
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{\Large-\frac{x^2}{y^2}-y^2}\ dx=\dfrac{|y|}{2}\sqrt{\pi}e^{\Large-y^2}.
$$

Comment: The $\large y$ pre-factor in the solution must be $\large\left\vert\,y\,\right\vert$. Otherwise, your solution is quite fine.

Comment: @FelixMarin Indeed, you're correct. I missed that. Thanks for pointing that out, I've fixed it.